# Solving inequalities graphically

Tags: inequality

**The question is :**

Let a,b,c be positive numbers.

There are infinitely many positive whole numbers x,y which satisfy the inequality
$a^x$ > $cb^y$ if

option 1 : a > 1 or b < 1

option 2 : a < 1 or b < 1

option 3 : a < 1 and b < 1

option 4 : a < 1 and b > 1

**My thinking is:**

If we let $y = a^x$ as (1) and $x = cb^y$ as (2), the question becomes "when is graph (1) higher than graph (2)"

Sketching (1) and (2) for part option 4, I land on the conclusion that the answer is option 4.

Is this a valid approach?
I tried for other questions where this line of reasoning didn’t quite hold?

[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9NnM.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9NnM.png): [image]

Thanks in advance for any help.